# absl.flags Error: Trying to access flag before flags were parsed

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse this flag 'dataroot' (string type).

Consider this as a demo code:

```
from absl import flags
from absl.flags import FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('dataroot',"D:\College",'path to root folder of dataset')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Hyperparameter
    # Root directory for dataset
    dataroot = FLAGS.dataroot
```

and this is what the error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Github/cloned repo/Image-Restoration-in-Occluded-Images-using-GANs/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    dataroot = FLAGS.dataroot
  File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\absl\flags\_flagvalues.py", line 498, in __getattr__
    raise _exceptions.UnparsedFlagAccessError(error_message)
absl.flags._exceptions.UnparsedFlagAccessError: Trying to access flag --dataroot before flags were parsed.
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Note, \ should be written using \\ in a string. So the path string becomes `"D:\\College"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I solved this by doing this:

```
from absl import flags
from absl.flags import FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('dataroot',"D:\College",'path to root folder of dataset')

def main(_argv):
    #Hyperparameter
    # Root directory for dataset
    dataroot = FLAGS.dataroot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(main)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

and this fixes the error..

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell flags library to parse argv using `FLAGS(sys.argv)` before you can access `FLAGS.xxx`. Calling `app.run()` is a way to do that implicitly.

Example without `app.run()` by using explicit call to `FLAGS(sys.argv)`:

```
  from absl import flags
  import sys
  flags.DEFINE_string('dataroot',"D:\\College",'path to root folder of dataset')
  FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
  FLAGS(sys.argv)   # need to explicitly to tell flags library to parse argv before you can access FLAGS.xxx
  dataroot = FLAGS.dataroot
```